# Setup existing drupal 6 site on local server

Tags: 6, database, importing-exporting

so far I've worked with Drupal 7 sites and have no experience importing Drupal 6 site to local server, so maybe you could help. I have 2 folders and .sql database file.

1. First folder is named 'files' which has sub-folder 'design' which consist all files stored in site (css, images, js, models etc.).
2. Second folder is named 'sites' which has two sub-folders - 'themes', 'models' and settings.php file.

I'm using Acquia Dev Desktop 2. So far I've created new site and database importing .sql dump file. And have plain text entering the site. Where should I override these two folders and should I rename them? My project is called 'project.dd', should 'design' folder be called as project name?

Comment: There is no need to rename inside directories. Just import the database as you do in d7.

Comment: @SumitMadan Yes, after importing database i get plain text onscreen. I still got to place that design and file folder somewhere, but where. And also importing database I get an error 'You have no access to this page.'

Comment: Can you explain the steps you taken including folder path and what is your OS?

Comment: @SumitMadan So far. I Created new project in Acquia. Imported database under the same name as it was. Entering site I see plain text. Then I added design folder in path .../sites/. Now I see some design elements but still not all of them. I still have to add file folder somewhere and in browser i get an error 'ACCESS DENIED.
You are not authorized to access this page.' and I don't have authentication data. Im operating on Win 8.1

Comment: Well, why are you not just putting the drupal folder in htdocs and installing the database? You just need to change in settings.php file?

Comment: @SumitMadan Sorry, is there any guide doing that. I've never worked with drupal 6. And where then does design and file folders go to?

Comment: Check my answer with steps. Let me know if you find any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to setup a Drupal Site :

1. Place your Drupal 6 directory in your `htdocs` directory of `xampp` folder. All files and design folder should be at same place where they are on live version of site.
2. Open your `settings.php`, change the database credentials according to your local server.
3. Restore your database using `phpmyadmin`.
4. May be some image would not be shown up on site so you need to setup a domain in apache's `vhost` file.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm able to import site just with design and file folder. Don't I also need the whole setup folder? Or default should work?

Comment: Well you can just download the drupal core and replace the sites folder.

Comment: Still nothing. As far as I can get is import the db. Then i have front page with plain text and message "No access". I've tried overriding sites file with folder given. I've tried to add files folder to sites/default folder. I've tried to add 'sites' content to /sites/all/themes and /sites/all/modules still nothing.

Comment: And also which particular settings.php file do I have to edit, because I got settings.php in /sites/design and /sites/default

Comment: Have you setup the multisite?

Comment: So what I did step by step and what makes logical sense to me. 1. Created database - d6_design. 2. Imported database given - d6_design.sql. 3. Created sites/all/themes and added given 'design' folder. 4. Created sites/all/models and added given 'models' folder. 5. Overridden sites/default settings.php with given. Changed $db_url to my db root. Now i have these table and function errors. http://imgur.com/fcAXkmA

Comment: Now I somehow managed to get to the page. Page is under maintenance and i have no access to database.